# AWS EventBridge Event not triggering lambda function with proper permission

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I have an eventbridge rule and it's configured with a lambda as a trigger. The eventbridge rule is a time based cronjob, I'm facing an issue with the eventbridge that it's not triggering the lambda function. I came across few answers and added **lambda:InvokeFunction** permission on lambda to the role but it's still not resolved yet.

[image]

Can anyone help me on this? The policy is added as part of terraform **aws_lambda_permission** to the lambda function. The lambda function is written in .Net

My terraform policy looks like this -

```
resource aws_lambda_permission allow_lambda_invoke {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromEventBridge"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.account_derive_and_publish_notes_handler.function_name
  principal     = aws_iam_role.account_lambda_role.arn
}
```

Comment: "terraform aws_lambda_permission" - what is your full TF code with the policy?

Comment: @Marcin - I just added the TF code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For EventBridge, `principal` **should be** `events.amazonaws.com`, not your function ARN.

Comment: ok, but then source_arn is mandatory? The lambda function will be triggered by multiple rules, how to handle that?

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana Please check [TF docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp%20%20/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission). The first example explains how to use EB and lambda, including `source_arn`.

Comment: I've gone through the document, and it says eventbridge rule arn should be passed in ```source_arn```, but in my case multiple rules will trigger the lambda, how to specify source_arn then?

Comment: @BiswajitMaharana use Asterix to specify all rules or based on prefix. But anyway, these comments go off topic. Your question was about the issue of "not triggering a lambda". I provided the correct answer why it happens and how to fix it. If you have new issues, such as with `source_arn`, please make new question, specifically dedicated to that new problem.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple rules invoke the same lambda function add Source ARN like:
arn:aws:events:YOUR_REGION:YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID:rule/*

[image: See my Resource-based policy statement:]